# Redirect due to browser?

Tags: browser, redirect

I am wondering if there is a way to redirect users using a specific browser to a different page?

Comment: If you want to send IE visitors to `http://getfirefox.com`, just use conditional comments `:p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script> window.location='http://getfirefox.com'; </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

First you could use [JavaScript to detect the browser](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp), and then you could set the `window.location` variable for the redirect.

Comment: Can you break that down elementary for me, my javascript experience is pretty limited :/